# Erratic behavior of GCC's std::sort with lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda, stl

The following code generates a segmentation fault when compiled with GCC 6.1.0. Strangely, the error is consistent, but does not happen with smaller sizes or slightly different comparison expressions.
Do you guys have any idea why?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int n = 1000;   
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        vec.push_back(std::make_pair<double, double>((7*i)%3, (3*i)%5));
    }
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](std::pair<double, double> const & p1, std::pair<double, double> const & p2) {return (p1.first < p2.first) || ((p1.first==p2.first)&& (p1.second <= p2.second));}); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should know that if all you want is a lexicogrphic comparison, then `std::pair` already does that without intervention on your part.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the tip. But what is really bothering me right now is the source of the segmentation fault!

Comment: The source is in your comparison not inducing a proper order relation. The code has undefined behavior on account of it.

Comment: You comparison needs to implement a [strict weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) - yours does *not* do so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing

```
(p1.second <= p2.second)
```

with

```
(p1.second < p2.second)
```

I mean... `std::sort()` need a comparator that return `true` iff (if and only if) the first argument (`p1`) is **strictly** lower than the second one (`p2`). That is: must return `false` when `p1` is equal to `p2`.

If your test is

```
   (p1.first < p2.first)
|| ((p1.first==p2.first)&& (p1.second <= p2.second))
```

you obtain `true` also when `p1` is equal to `p2`.

With a comparator that return `true` when `p1` is equal to `p2`... if I'm not wrong the behavior is undefined so an "erratic behavior" (and a segmentation fault also) is absolutely understandable.

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that your lambda does not meet the standard requirements for `Compare`, which requires a ***strict*** weak ordering:

- **strict** implies that `!comp(x, x)` must be `true` for every `x` in the sequence, which is not the case for your custom comparator (lambda) since `comp(x, x) == true` for every `x` in your case (`x.first == x.first && x.second <= x.second`).

You should either change `p1.second <= p2.second` to `p1.second < p2.second`, or use the standard comparison operator for `std::pair`:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

Libstdc++ has a [debug mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html) which can be enabled by defining the macro `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`.

```
$ g++-6 b.cc -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG && ./a.out
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:4737:
Error: comparison doesn't meet irreflexive requirements, assert(!(a < a)).

Objects involved in the operation:
    instance "functor" @ 0x0x7ffe48ba5a20 {
      type = main::{lambda(std::pair<double, double> const&, std::pair<double, double> const&)#1};
    }
    iterator::value_type "ordered type" {
      type = std::pair<double, double>;
    }
```